# How to resolve Luis - 403 Out of call volume quota

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am testing my bot for my school project which was due in next two days and suddenly, the bot stopped functioning correctly and showing the default message all the time.

After some research in Google and Stackoverflow, found it is due to Quota limit.

I see in the Luis keys, the current key is "Starter_key" and also below error message in the end-point.

```
{ "statusCode": 403, "message": "Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in 11.00:25:53." }
```

I read similar problems here, but none of them clearly mentioned what next. What is the best possible way to overcome this and I dont want to wait for the next 11 days. Is there anyway to upgrade to pay-as-you-go only for Luis? or even that wont work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your error message indicates, you simply hit the max amount of request for your LUIS Starter_Key (which is sort of a trial).

To **permanently** resolve this issue you need to **provision a LUIS resource on your Microsoft Azure Subscription** and use the subscription keys from there.

The approach is well documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription).

**In short:**

- Create a LUIS Resource within your Azure Subscription
- Back in your LUIS portal go to *Keys and Endpoints* of your model
- Click "Assign resource" and select the previously created LUIS Resource

Answer (score -3):

I resolved the problem with below steps and this can be marked as closed.

1. Created New Luis app in luis.ai using different account.
2. Exported the existing account settings from My Apps -> Export as Json.
3. Imported the Json into new app under Manage -> Versions
4. Trained and published the new Luis app.
5. Copy the new app's App ID and API key and update them in the Bot Application settings --> LuisAPIKey and LuisAppId
6. Restart the Bot service.
7. Validate the Bot.

Comment: You have to mark this as solved yourself. This isn't a solution though, it's more like a workaround to not pay for the resource...

Comment: Would you mind considering marking my response as the correct final solution? There is no benefit/reputation for you and my answer is the correct one for the root cause of your issue.

Comment: this is not an answer or a solution on how one would resolve this issue.  This is literally saying, start a new account.  Well of course that would work but it isn't resolving anything the op was questioning