# Azure Luis Response 403: Total monthly key quota limit exceeded

Tags: azure, bots

I think I reached the limit on Luis. I created a new Luis account and tried to change the bot Luis configuration but I still get the same error. All I changed is the APPId in Mybot.bot file. Is that all I need to change? or do I need to change other stuff? Please help! Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319739/how-to-resolve-luis-403-out-of-call-volume-quota

Comment: I create and assign authoring and prediction runtime keys, to replace the starter key functionality but it's still giving me error